# compilation errors in powerdot. Can some one help?

Tags: errors, powerdot

```
\documentclass[mode=present,style=elcolors]{powerdot}
\pdsetup{
lf=my first presentation,
rf=for some conference,
trans=wipe,
theslide=\english{slide},
randomdots,dmaxdots=80
}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{basic itemize}
Contents of the slide.
\end{slide}
\section{first section}
\begin{slide}[<slide options>]{another slide}
Contents of the slide.
\end{slide}
\begin{note}{personal note}
The note.
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

error messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.12 \end{slide}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@
\else \expandafter \expand...
l.12 \end{slide}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.12 \end{slide}
```

Comment: You cannot compile directly with `pdflatex`. Use `latex` or `xelatex`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gonzalo's correct reply that you need to run it with latex, not pdflatex:

there are other small issues in your code

- replace \english{slide} by \arabic{slide} (this is the numbering of the slide, not a language thing!
- remove [] from your second slide (or add actual valid options; this is meant an indication of where options might be entered)